# Stream live audio using Socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io, getusermedia

I created a small project to stream live audio using Socket.io. The problem is that this only works when I test it in the same chrome window. When another computer tries to listen or broadcast it can't. This is the message that appears in the other computer:

```
GET blob:https://server/ce74cfe7-bb9c-40b0-9cb0-1138b22b1b11 404 (Not Found)
```

This is the code in main.js (website):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var socket = io("https://server:4000", verify=false);
    socket.on('audio stream', function(name, blob){
        var video = document.querySelector('video');
        video.src = blob;
    });
    $('#ptt').click(function(){
        micOn();
        document.getElementById("ptt").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("ptt-off").disabled = false;
    });
    $('#ptt-off').click(function(){
        stream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
        document.getElementById("ptt").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("ptt-off").disabled = true;
    });
    function micOn(){
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

        var constraints = {
            audio: true,
            video: false
        };
        var video = document.querySelector('video');

        function successCallback(stream) {
            window.stream = stream; // stream available to console
            var blob = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            socket.emit('audio stream', myName, blob);
        }

        function errorCallback(error) {
            console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
        }

        navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
    }
});
```

And this is the code on the server (index.js):

```
socket.on('audio stream', function(name, blob){
    console.log(name + ' is broadcasting audio');
    socket.broadcast.emit('audio stream', name, blob);
});
```